# How do I use Star Dust and Candy?

Tags: pokemon-go

When I click on a pokemon, I see information regarding stardust and candy, can I have more information on what this is, how to acquire it, how to use it?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the Arqade. We are a bit different than most sites in that we prefer one question per post. Also if you look around a bit a number of these question you have are already answered in a different question. Specifically, I know 1, 2, and 4 have already been asked and answered.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Didn't know, should I just edit my question or delete it?

Comment: You can edit it, I would suggest editing it to ask one of the questions there that you had that I didn't mention seeing before, such as #3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stardust and Candy are obtained by catching wild pokémon and hatching eggs. You'll get candy for that species.The Stardust and Candy let you evolve you pokémon or make it stronger.

Comment: I would edit your answer to be based on the current question and not a past edit of it.

Comment: Hatching eggs does in fact provide stardust and candy. In fact, you get more stardust with one egg hatching than you do by catching a pokemon.

Comment: I haven't hatched any egg so that's why I didn't know that